# Spell check for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, spellcheck

We need a reliable spell check application for Internet Explorer (running IE6, 7 & 8) for our corporation.  Currently other browsers are not part of our standard PC build, nor does security and networking wish to add one at this time.

Could you please recommend a integral spell check option for IE we could use across our enterprise.  It must support localization.

Thank you.

Comment: It's funny when somebody uses IE6, but does not want to install any other browser for SECURITY reasons :). np.
Firefox can be run as portable app, so there is no need to install it.

Answer (score 4):

The Google Toolbar provides [a bunch of features](http://www.google.com/support/toolbar/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=15360), including spellchecking and works with IE6 and 7 (I have not tested it on 8). Google does have an [Enterprise version of the toolbar](http://toolbar.google.com/enterprise) and also has a [google group on using and setting it up](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Toolbar-for-Enterprise/topics).

Answer (score 2):

This is the only one I'm aware of:
http://www.iespell.com/

Answer (score 1):

The addon [IE7Pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/) has an integrated spell checker as well as a bunch of other features. One caveat is that it does not play well with IE 8

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use GPO to push out IESpell to your workstations?